# in magento sales_order_aggregated_created database table is not getting updated after magento updation from 1.5 to 1.9.2.1

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

In Magento `sales_order_aggregated_created` database table is not getting updated after Magento updating `from 1.5 to 1.9.2.1`. so the report order is not working for day and month report. It shows data before Magento upgrade. Because of this chart is also working on the dashboard. P.S. I have used `AITOC extension and extendware both`.

p.p.s. I have used mageworx orders pro extension as well.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the lifetime statistic refresh instead of the daily statistic refresh.